# PL/SQL efficient method to compare large set of columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have trigger on the table having 100+ columns. Is there any efficient method on oracle to compare set of columns and determine that NEW values are NOT equal to OLD values instead of checking every single column?

I am looking some kind of unique number generation like MAC on set of columns. And then compare OLD mac with NEW mac??

Comment: I don't know of any built-in mechanism to do this other than explicit.  You could concatenate all the column values into a string for the old/new and then compare the two string?  Not efficient and size is limited.  I am curious if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following solution works for me in AFTER Trigger code logic...

```
SELECT ora_hash( old.ename || old.empno || old.sal ) INTO v_old_hash FROM dual
SELECT ora_hash( new.ename || new.empno || new.sal ) INTO v_new_hash FROM dual
```

And then compare

```
IF v_old_hash <> v_new_hash THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('Record Change flag');
END IF;
```

Comment: This could run into a lot of different problems though.  What if the final string is > 4000 characters, some data types will require conversion, and there are some scenarios where different rows could generate the same string.  For example, if two columns swapped positions and one of them was null.

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL VARCHAR2 size is 32,767. For me, max data length of columns is 14,000 (SELECT sum(data_length) FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name =?)

Comment: Yes, but ora_hash is not available in PL/SQL.  If you run it in a SELECT statement then the 4000 limit applies.  Also, data_length is not always the true max length.  For CLOBs it represents the maximum length that is stored inline.  These are all weird errors, but why take the risk?  Also, if you're concerned about efficiency in terms of performance, running a select inside a trigger will cause yet another context switch.  This is probably one of those times when the ugly, old way is best.

Answer (score 4):

I typically still test each column individually to be safer.  This is a little bit of a pain, but I just use the database to generate the code for me:

```
select ':old.'||column_name||' <> :new.'||column_name||' or'
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

I then copy the results and paste it into my trigger (deleting the extra "or" at the end).  Obviously it would be much better if you could just do :new <> :old, so lets hope that is possible in the next Oracle version.

Comment: excellent point.. if nulls are possible, you will need to update the code to check those cases as well as inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not compare records. Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS496):

> **Record Comparisons**
>
> Records cannot be tested natively for nullity, equality, or
>   inequality. These BOOLEAN expressions are illegal:
>
> ```
> - My_Record IS NULL
> - My_Record_1 = My_Record_2
> - My_Record_1 > My_Record_2
> ```
>
> You must write your own functions to implement such tests.

The easiest way would be to write a procedure that accepts two records (old and new) and returns true/false if the records are equal/not equal. Than use the procedure in the trigger.

How does the procedure check for equality is up to you - either compare every single field or concatenate all the fields and compare the two strings. A hash of the concatenated string could also be used, but you probably know that hashes can collide.